# How to get the first post and second post in a wordpress blog?

Tags: plugins, posts

is there a way I can retrieve the first and second post in wordpress...

I have tried using get_post() but with that I have to put in a id. What if I don't know the posts id?

Comment: How do you define "first and second"? Earliest by date posted?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `WP_Query()`?

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2' );
```

You can also split it into two quieries if you must, with an offset:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ); // First post
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset=1' ) ); // Second post
```